# LU composition of a tridiagonal matrix

Tags: proof-explanation, matrix-decomposition, tridiagonal-matrices

Given a triadiagonal Matrix A with

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 &e1\\
c_2 & d_2 & e_2 \\
& c_3 & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & e_{n-1} \\
& & & c_n & d_n \\
\end{bmatrix} \quad
$$

Assume that A is invertible and has a LU factorization.

Proof that L and U have this structure:

$$
L = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
l_2 & 1 \\
& l_3 & \ddots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & & l_n & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \quad
U = \begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & e_1 \\
& u_2 & e_2 \\
& & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & & \ddots & e_{n-1} \\
& & & & u_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I've found out, that an invertible matrix has diagonal elements $\neq 0$.
I tried to start by A and do a LU factorization, but I couldn't get to the needed structure. Than I've read that this could be shown by induction.

So the simplest case should be $n = 2$. Then I would have 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & e_1 \\
c_2 & d_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
L = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
l_2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
U = \begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & e_1 \\
0 & u_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now, I don't know how to show that this case is true. In all literature I just found the comment, that this is trivial, but I don't understand why. I also don't know how to show for further cases by induction that the structure must hold. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true in general.

$$L = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
l_2 & 1 \\& & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & & l_n & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \quad
U = \begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & e_1 \\
& u_2 & e_2 \\
& & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & & \ddots & e_{n-1} \\
& & & & u_n \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
will generate the same product $LU$ as $2L$ and $(1/2) U$

Comment: No, I meant the factorization is not unique. You do not have to have ones on the diagonal.

Comment: I had overlooked the "not" first.
Even if A is invertible? I found the statement also in another source, but without a proof.